# use avatar image in xmpp and ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, avatar

I am creating a text chat application and using Ejabberd server and strophe.js.

I am using mssql as a external database for ejabberd. I transferred all the application users in users table and freinds in rosterusers table of ejabberd.

I want to specify the profile image url of application as a avatar image of ejabberd user.

Where to insert the avatar URL in ejabberd database ? I checked vcard table but no column for avatar image url ?

Can we handle it using the ejabberd database or ejabberd is managing avatars internally ?

If we can't manage the avatars in ejabberd than how can we use it with strophe.js i.e. sepcify the avatar image and receive other roster items avatar image ?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set VCard Image from URL:**

I know the profile image of user and after making the connection to the ejabberd server using strophe i am setting profile image in vcard using the strophe stanza.

Below is example of setting the image url in the vcard:

```
iq = $iq({ type: 'set', to: currentUserObj.jabberid+ "@" + CDomain }).c('vCard', { xmlns:'vcard-temp' }).c('PHOTO').c('EXTVAL', currentUserObj.profileImg);

connection.sendIQ(iq);
```

Hope it'll help someone :)

Comment: Does this really work? I was looking at the spec (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) and it seemed clear that you weren't supposed to use EXTVAL in that context. To quote 4.5.2: "The <PHOTO/> element SHOULD NOT contain an <EXTVAL/> that points to a URI for the image file."

Comment: Yes its working for us in web app. On mobile apps we are using another mechanism.

Comment: @RohitTailor Thanks for the answer. Would like to know what is 'currentUserObj.profileImg' in your code, is it a file url of file upload or base64 string?

Comment: currentUserObj.profileImg is the URL of image (Amazon S3 URL). Sorry for delay in response.

Comment: Hello @RohitTailor Can you please let me know which mechanism you have used for mobile app?
Because I have suffering for same problem in mobile app.

Comment: Hi @ChiragSolankI I have used  XMPPFramework https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for IOS  app.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the command `ejabberctl` from the command line to load avatar URLs into a user's vcard.

```
ejabberdctl set_vcard foo chat.myjabber.com PHOTO http://link_to_image.jpg
ejabberdctl set_vcard2 foo chat.myjabber.com PHOTO EXTVAL http://link_to_image.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks slm. Actually i am creating the chat in web app and do not want to build a module to call command line utility from external php or other script.